# Should GWT Activities/Places be Singletons or Prototypes?

Tags: java, gwt, singleton, gwt-places, gwt-activities

What's the difference (performance and otherwise) between this:

```
public class MyPlaceMapper implements PlaceHistoryMapper {
    @Override
    public String getToken(Place place) {
        if(place instanceof HomePlace)
            return "home";
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Place getPlace(String token) {
        if(token.equals("home"))
            return new HomePlace();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class MyPlaceMapper implements PlaceHistoryMapper {
    // Singleton HomePlace to inject and reuse over and over again
    private HomePlace homePlace;

    // Getter/setter for homePlace...

    @Override
    public String getToken(Place place) {
        if(place instanceof HomePlace)
            return "home";
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Place getPlace(String token) {
        if(token.equals("home"))
            return homePlace;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

In other words, what's the difference whether I keep reusing the same "singleton" `Place` over and over again, or if I just instantiate a new one every time it is requested.

Also, same question for `Activity`s from inside the `ActivityMapper`. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @SergeyVedernikov but your comment doesn't really help me out. It doesn't provide any explanation of the differences to either strategy. I'm asking because Activities can be started and stopped, and multiple Places of the same class can be fired onto the EventBus, and I'm wondering what the impact is on having multiple "prototypes" of these classes working at the same time.

Comment: Ok. When you create new `Place` object and return this object in getPlace, this object will be cleared from memory after `Activity` is stopped. For activities the same situation. But if you will store all of this objects in mappers, you will use more client's memory. While places is small objects, activities can be huge. I hope my explanation is clear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule of thumb: places should be immutable. With that in mind, using a singleton place can only be done if the place has no *data* attached to it (as in your `HomePlace` example). Because places are so lightweight, the implications of using a singleton vs. creating a new instance is negligible.

It's a totally different story for activities, because they aren't *value objects*.

What would it imply to use a singleton activity?

- you have to clear state in `onStop` and `onCancel`, otherwise state from a previous use of the activity could leak into a later use of it. While it's useful in some cases, I think it's better to keep the *caching* behavior separate (separation of concerns).
- singletons are by definition kept in memory for the lifetime of the application, even those that the user will only see/use once. For instance, the *welcome* screen of Google Groups is likely to ever be seen only once per application run, so why keep it in memory?
- if you navigate between two places that both map to the same activity, the activity won't be restarted (this is a feature of the `ActivityMapper`), so you have to somehow signal to the activity that the place has changed (if needed of course). This can be done in the `ActivityMapper` or by having the activity listen to `PlaceChangeEvent`s.

If you use MVP (splitting the view out of the activity), activities are generally lightweight, so using short-lived ones frees you from the above *make sure you clear everything in `onStop` and `onCancel`* and *tell the activity the place has changed* and overall makes things simpler: the activity is created, then started, then cancelled or stopped and it's gone, ready to be garbage-collected. If you need to keep a cache of some data or computation results, then use an explicit cache object that all your activity instances will share; it makes things clearer.

---

A side note about MVP and views lifecycle: views (widgets) are generally heavyweight, so for often-used ones you might want to make them singletons. In this case, your activity will have to clear the state of the view (field values, etc.) in its `start` method (or possibly `onStop` and `onCancel`), somehow defeating the use of short-lived activities. The *caching* of the view (you might consider not using a singleton but rather keeping the instance in memory for some time and evicting it after some delay) should be viewed as an optimization here, where constructing a new view costs much than clearing it on activity start. It's a tradeoff.

The way I approach MVP is that the view has no *state* on its own, that is the presenter really controls what the view should display/know/etc. so clearing the view on `start` is part of the flow: the presenter (the activity in many cases) knows what state it's in, and it reflects that state in the view; and `start` is the time when it's given the control of the view. That approach was described by Google, in the making of Wave, during Google I/O 2010 in the [GWT testing best practices](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/gwt-continuous-build-testing.html) session.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by Thomas. Just to add some more information.

You can decide to override the default implementation of the objects given by google. For example you can decide to write your own activity mapper that will always give back the same instance of activity for a given type of place. As said by Thomas the place is not really an important object. It is the activity linked with that Place through the activity mapper that matters. Nonetheless you might have lifecycle problems and coding you start and stop methods will be very difficult.

You might want to recode the activity manager and add an update method to the pattern to refresh an existing activity if that is what you want to do

Ask yourself how you application should behave when pressing forward or backward in your browser. [You can find some more details in an article I wrote about Activities and Places here.](http://wpamm.blogspot.fr/2013/03/gwt-activity-place-introduction.html)

Hope it will help.